# Multiprocessing Alchemy Catalyst execution asynchronically

Tags: c#, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm trying to execute several processes that run Alchemy Catalyst with parameters and make some operations (working with Catalyst API ). The problem is to run them asynchronous.

machine with 8 processors - in the beginning of the execution ( in program that uses 2 processes ) i get 2 running Catalyst programs as i want. You can see that they running by getting CPU time -> see (first picture) picture . 
Then after several seconds one of them suddenly was blocked and doesn't get CPU time anymore (second picture ). That's continue until first process finished his work .

I have a feeling that Catalyst does't support multiprocessing .

But i can't explain to myself how it possible to make leverage on two different instances of Catalyst . 
thanks a lot .

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Japanese jp = new Japanese();
        Brasilian br = new Brasilian();

        jp.startNPprocess();
        br.startNPprocess();

    }
}
public class Japanese
{
    public void startNPprocess()
    {
        string brz = @"D:\Builder\master\Languages\Destination_TTK\jap";
        string brz1 = "D:\\Builder\\master\\Languages\\TTK\x64\\jap.ttk";
        string brz2 = "D:\\Builder\\master\\Languages\\Destination_TTK\\TTK\\jap.ttk";
        string pathtoCatalyst = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Alchemy Software\Catalyst 10.0\Catalyst.exe";
        string args = String.Format("/M Vasili TTKName:{0} FromFolder:{1} SourceLang:English(United States) TargetLang:Japanese", brz2, brz);           
        Process pr = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo prs = new ProcessStartInfo();
        prs.FileName = pathtoCatalyst;
        prs.Arguments = args;
        pr.StartInfo = prs;

        pr.Start();

    }
}
}




class Brasilian
{
    public void startNPprocess()
    {
        string brz = @"D:\Builder\master\Languages\Destination_TTK\brz";
        string brz1 = "D:\\Builder\\master\\Languages\\TTK\x64\\brz.ttk";
        string brz2 = "D:\\Builder\\master\\Languages\\Destination_TTK\\TTK\\brz.ttk";
        string pathtoCatalyst = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Alchemy Software\Catalyst 10.0\Catalyst.exe";
        string args = String.Format("/M Vasili TTKName:{0} FromFolder:{1} SourceLang:English(United States) TargetLang:Portuguese(Brazil)", brz2, brz);

        // Prepare the process to run
        Process pr = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo prs = new ProcessStartInfo();

        prs.FileName = pathtoCatalyst;
        prs.Arguments = args;            
        pr.StartInfo = prs;
        pr.Start();
    }
}
```

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWC2v.jpg)

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YiiE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

After talking with Catalyst support and making a lot of research there is no way to implement multiprocessing execution using API of Catalyst.

Alchemy Catalyst program use client-server model to check if you have a valid license. After validation is completed you have access to program. 
If you want to get access to features of the program via API you don't need license. There is some bug in implementation that giving you option to make leverage\validate\get-statistics for free , with one restriction - one instance of Catalyst running.